I am trying to use gRPC between .NET 6.0 as a service and .NET 4.7 as Client side. I am getting an error on the Client side it doesnt support HTTP2
I have a solution built on .NET 6.0 and I want to use its functions from another solution restricted to .NET 4.7. I am getting an error when using GRPC on the client.
The first trial was on .NET 6.0 server and .NET 6.0 client on a windows 10 OS and it worked fine. Now the client is restricted to .NET 4.7 and the communication is not possible, I believe it is because .NET 4.7 does not support HTTP/2 while 6.0 supports it, so I need a work around to do the binding process Bind.
Code used in server side:
string gRPCNetworkIP = "127.0.0.1";
int gRPCNetworkPort = 50051;

//Creating gRPC service and Starting gRPC Network
Console.WriteLine("Creating gRPC service and Starting gRPC Network...");
var server = gRPCNetworkCongig(samsungGalaxyA50Driver, gRPCNetworkIP, gRPCNetworkPort);
Console.WriteLine("gRPC service and gRPC Network are created and started");


Console.ReadKey();

public static Server gRPCNetworkCongig(Driver driver, string gRPCIP, int gRPCPort)
{
    Server server = new Server();

    server.Ports.Add(new ServerPort(gRPCIP, gRPCPort, ServerCredentials.Insecure));

    server.Services.Add(DriverService_gRPC.DriverService_gRPC.BindService(new DriverService(driver)));

    

    // Start the gRPC server
    server.Start();
    return server;
}

Code used in client side:
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string gRPCNetworkIP = "127.0.0.1";
        int gRPCNetworkPort = 50051;
        string desiredDevice_1 = "CUO 4B2A";
        string desiredDevice_2 = "BT-S2";
        string desiredDevice_3 = "BLA";

        string baseAddress = $"http://{gRPCNetworkIP}:{gRPCNetworkPort}";

        var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(baseAddress);

        var client = new DriverService_gRPC.DriverService_gRPC.DriverService_gRPCClient(channel);

        //await client.OpenSettingsAsync(new OpenSettingsRequest());

        testcase_BT(client, desiredDevice_2);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static async void testcase_BT(DriverService_gRPC.DriverService_gRPC.DriverService_gRPCClient driver, string desiredDevice)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Openning Bluetooth Settings ...");
        await driver.OpenBluetoothSettingsAsync(new OpenBluetoothSettingsRequest());
        Console.WriteLine("Bluetooth Settings Openned");

        Console.WriteLine($"Reading {desiredDevice} state ...");
        var readStateResponse = await driver.ReadDeviceStateAsync(new ReadDeviceStateRequest { DesiredDevice = desiredDevice });

        Console.WriteLine($"{desiredDevice} is {readStateResponse.State}");

        Console.WriteLine("Testcase ended");
    }

Now I have the same server and the same client but the only thing different is the client side is .NET 4.7 and now I am getting this error

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The channel configuration isn't valid on this operating system. The channel is configured to use WinHttpHandler and the current version of Windows doesn't support HTTP/2 features required by gRPC. Windows Server 2022 or Windows 11 or later is required. For more information, see https://aka.ms/aspnet/grpc/netframework.'

It doesnt make sense because the OS worked fine in the first trial so it should be the framework version.

Could you include the comment from staging ground where you stated "the first trial was on .NET 6.0 server and .NET 6.0 client on a windows 10 OS. Now the client is restricted to .NET 4.7."? I feel like it might be relevant.

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/2295

https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/8094
